# Is $f : [0,\infty) \rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, $ f(x) = \frac{25}{x^2 + 10x + 25}$ injective, surjective, bijective?

Tags: functions

I'm struggling with understanding how to prove that the following function is injective, surjective, or bijective:

Let $f : [0,\infty) \rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined by,

$$ f(x) = \frac{25}{x^2 + 10x + 25}$$

So far for the injective part I've figured that I'd use the $f(a) = f(b)$ approach:

$$ \frac{25}{a^2 + 10a + 25} = \frac{25}{b^2 + 10b + 25} $$

Simplified, this is what I get

$$ a^2 + 10a = b^2 + 10b$$ But don't really know how to get it into the $a = b$ form.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with the subject tag "linear algebra". The properties of injectivity, surjectivity, and bijectivity are applicable to all functions, not just the functions that come up in linear algebra.

Comment: When talking about whether or not a function is injective, bijective, or whatnot... it is necessary first to *adequately define the function*.  You have only given part of the definition of the function, namely, a method of calculating the output given a particular input.  You have not explicitly told us what the domain or the codomain of the function are... necessary pieces of information to the conversation.  Depending on the choice of domain and codomain, the function might be both injective and surjective, only one or the other, or neither... possibly not even being a valid function at all

Comment: Things to consider: $x^2+10x+25 = (x+5)^2$.  So... what happens when $x=-5$?  Is $f(-6) = f(-4)$?  Is $f(x)$ ever negative?

Comment: With the edit you gave the domain.  You did not give the codomain.

Comment: Then the codomain is supposed to be $\mathbb{R}$ :-)

Comment: before your question gets deleted, edit your question to include your latest attempt.

Comment: @AwhatLoop With the hints JMoravitz gave you, you should be able to conclude. If you need clarifications please include them in your post. And yes, if you do not show research effort as Siong Thye Goh mentions, your question will likely be downvoted then closed.

Comment: Hint: $a^2 + 10a + 25 = (a + 5)^2$. Can $(a + 5)^2 = (b + 5)^2$ for $a, b \in [0, \infty)$, $a \neq b$?

Answer (score 1):

First note that,

$$\forall x \in [0, +\infty), \quad f(x) = \left(\dfrac{5}{x+5}\right)^2$$

**Injectivity:**

Following what you wanted to do,

Let $(a,b) \in [0,\infty)^2$ then if $f(a) = f(b)$ then,

$$f(a) -f(b)= \left(\dfrac{5}{a+5}\right)^2-\left(\dfrac{5}{b+5}\right)^2 =0$$

Hence using remarkable identity $x^2-y^2 =(x-y)(x+y)$  we have,

$$\left(\dfrac{5}{a+5}-\dfrac{5}{b+5} \right) \left(\dfrac{5}{a+5}+\dfrac{5}{b+5} \right) =0$$

Therefore, whether $\dfrac{5}{a+5}=\dfrac{5}{b+5}$ which gives us $a=b$ or $\dfrac{5}{a+5}=-\dfrac{5}{b+5}$ giving $b+5=-a-5$ so $b= -a-10$

But $a$ and $b$ are nonnegative, therefore $b = -a-10$ is never true. Finally we have in any case $a=b$ so $f$ is injective.

**Surjectivity:**

$f$ is always nonnegative, and as your codomain is $\mathbb{R}$ then for example $-1$ is not reached hence $f$ is not surjective.

**Bijectivity**: $f$ is not bijective as it is not surjective.

Comment: More generally, you could also see that $\dfrac{5}{x+5}$ is positive and injective on $(-5,+\infty)$ so as $x \mapsto x^2$ is injective on $[0,+\infty)$ then by composition $f$ is injective on $(-5,+\infty)$.